# What is the name of this hat and the function of those wearing them (worn by Nansouty's French Guard cavalry)?

Tags: identification, napoleonic-wars, clothing

Horace Vernet's painting "[Battle of Hanau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hanau#/media/File:Vernet-Battle_of_Hanau.jpg)", held at the National Gallery in London. This scene depicts the Austro-Bavarian cavalry charge on the French Grand Battery and the countercharge of Nansouty's French Guard cavalry.

Right next to [General Nansouty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tienne_Marie_Antoine_Champion_de_Nansouty) (with his back to the viewer with the powdered wig) at the [Battle of Hanau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hanau) there is a cavalryman with a red hat that starts round and ends square on the top.
What is this hat called and the function of this individual?

[image]

Comment: They're Polish lancers. For future reference, I typed 'napoleonic wars uniform hats' into google and the preview pane of the images (not the images page itself) showed this hat.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the tip. This will save me and the people researching a lot of time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the headgear of the [1st Polish Guard Light Cavalry (Lancers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Polish_Light_Cavalry_Regiment_of_the_Imperial_Guard)

[image]

> High (22 cm) [czapkas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czapka) had their forehead metals made of brass (officer's of silver) with a rising sun and the letter "N". For the parade czapka was crowned with 47 cm long plume of heron's or ostrich white feathers,[32] and a cockade with a blue center, broad crimson middle band and a narrow white outer edging, with the blue practically hidden under the silver Maltese cross.

[image]

The [French Order of Battle at Hanau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanau_order_of_battle) shows Nansouty commanding the Imperial Guard Cavalry:

> Imperial Guard cavalry (4,000 men), under the command of General Etienne de Nansouty:
>
> > - 1st division under Philippe Antoine d'Ornano:
> >
> >   > - Brigade Pierre David de Colbert-Chabanais
> >   >
> >   >   - Berg lancers (6 sq.)
> >   >   - 2e régiment de chevau-légers lanciers de la Garde Impériale (10 sq.)
> >   > - Brigade Pinteville:
> >   >
> >   >   - Dragoons of the Young Guard (2 sq.)
> > - 2nd division under Charles Lefebvre-Desnouettes:
> >
> >   > - Brigade Bertrand Pierre Castex:
> >   >
> >   >   - **1er régiment de chevau-légers lanciers polonais de la Garde impériale, Young Guard (4 sq.)**
> >   >   - Chasseurs à Cheval de la Garde Impériale, Young Guard (4 sq.)
> >   >   - Grenadiers à Cheval de la Garde Impériale, Young Guard (2 sq.)
> > - 3rd division under Frédéric Henri Walther:
> >
> >   > - Brigade Jean-Dieudonné Lion:
> >   >
> >   >   - **1er régiment de chevau-légers lanciers polonais de la Garde impériale, Old Guard (3 sq.)**
> >   >   - 4th Gardes d'Honneur (4 sq.)
> >   >   - Chasseurs à Cheval de la Garde Impériale, Old Guard (6 sq.)
> >   > - Brigade Louis-Michel Letort de Lorville:
> >   >
> >   >   - 1st Gardes d'Honneur (4 sq.)
> >   >   - Dragoons of the Old Guard (4 sq.)
> >   >   - 2nd Gardes d'Honneur (4 sq.)
> >   > - Brigade Louis-Marie Lévesque de Laferrière:
> >   >
> >   >   - Grenadiers à Cheval de la Garde Impériale, Old Guard (4 sq.)
> >   >   - 3rd Gardes d'Honneur (4 sq.)

Comment: You sure know your Napoleonic wars! I know i have seen the headwear in London but English cavalry helping France did not seem right to me.